# replace function arguments with a list element by element

Tags: replacement

I have a list of numerical functions (interpolation functions) that I'd like to get the values of each one at different points. For example: the functions are
`{y1[t],y2[t]}` and the points are `{t1, t2}`; I'd like to get the result `{y1[t1], y2[t2]}`.

I used `Diagonal` to get the answer:

```
Diagonal[{y1[t],y2[t]}/. t-> {t1,t2}]
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to avoid unnecessary replacements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) does the trick:

```
In[1]:= MapThread[#[#2] &, {{y1, y2}, {t1, t2}}]
Out[1]= {y1[t1], y2[t2]}
```

Comment: If you don't mind using deprecated/undocumented functions, you could do `MapThread[Compose, {{y1, y2}, {t1, t2}}]` instead.

Comment: And `{y1,y2}` can be obtained as `{y1[t], y2[t]}[[All, 0]]` using the OP's input. Or `Head /@ {y1[t], y2[t]}`.

Comment: Thank you. Both methods work great. I ended up using Mapthread with Compose.

Answer (score 1):

`MapThread` is probably your best shot, and in particular this version most closely mirrors your original approach, which did not require extracting the heads or pure-function versions of the $y_i$:

```
MapThread[#1 /. t -> #2 &, {{y1[t], y2[t]}, {t1, t2}}]
```

You could do this directly using `Thread`:

```
Thread[f[{y1[t], y2[t]}, {t1, t2}]] /. f -> (#1 /. t -> #2 &)
```

By defining an auxially variable $t_i=\{t_1,t_2\}$, you could also do this using `MapIndexed`:

```
ti = {t1, t2};
MapIndexed[#1 /. t -> ti[[First@#2]] &, {y1[t], y2[t]}]
```

Comment: Thank you. very nice application of MapIndexed.